# Files copy line instead of replace line

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to edit the build.prop file by replacing 3 lines in the file. The following method leaves the original lines and copies the new ones to the new file. I need to replace the lines instead of adding new lines to it.
The origFile is pulled from system and a backup is created the following is a portion of the output file.

```
ro.product.model=Galaxy Nexus
ro.product.model=SCH-I605
ro.product.brand=samsung
ro.product.name=yakju
ro.product.name=t0ltevzw
ro.product.device=Maguro
ro.product.device=t0ltecdma
```

I've updated my code to use the "else if" shown below

```
public void PropEdit() throws InterruptedException,IOException {
    String origFile="data/data/app.props/build.orig.prop";
    String propFile="data/data/app.props/build.new.prop";
    try{
        suProcess=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os=new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /data/data/app.props/build.new.prop\n");

        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(origFile));
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new File(propFile));

        String line;
        String params[];

        while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
            params=line.split("=");
            if (params[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ro.product.device")) {
                out.println(params[0]+"="+"Maguro");
                /**out.println(line); **/
                out.flush();
            } else if (params[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ro.product.name")) {
                out.println(params[0]+"="+"yakju");
                /**out.println(line); **/
                out.flush();
            } else if (params[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ro.product.model")) {
                out.println(params[0]+"="+"Galaxy Nexus");
                /**out.println(line); **/
                out.flush();
            }
            out.println(line);
        }
        boolean successful;
        {
            out.close();
            in.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            suProcess.waitFor();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please correct indentation. Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: @Miserable Variable I used phone, I'm sorry for the indentation issue I will fix as soon as I reach my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add an final `else` statement add put the last `println` there.

Like this

```
(...)
} else if (params[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ro.product.model")) {
    out.println(params[0]+"="+"Galaxy Nexus");
    /**out.println(line); **/
    out.flush();
} else {
    out.println(line);
}
(...)
```